# set datetime milliseconds precision - elixir

Tags: datetime, elixir, timex

I am trying to get a datetime which has only 3 digits in the sub-second part.
Using timex I get the following result:

```
iex(12)>   {:ok, date} = Timex.format(Timex.shift(Timex.local, days: 16), "{ISO:Extended}")
{:ok, "2017-04-22T09:00:44.403879+03:00"}
```

How can I get something like this:
{:ok, "2017-04-22T09:00:44.**403**+03:00"} ?

Comment: Did you try using the format string, e.g: `{:ok, date} = Timex.format(Timex.shift(Timex.local, days: 16), "%FT%T%:z", :strftime)`

Comment: @ZubairNabi, that gives me a result with no milliseconds, i can't figure out the right format string to get 3 milliseconds digits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DateTime` has a `microsecond` field which is a tuple containing the value and precision. If you change the precision to `3`, you'll get 3 digits in the microsecond output. I couldn't find any function in Timex which does this, but you can modify the value manually:

```
iex(1)> dt = %{microsecond: {us, precision}} = Timex.now
#<DateTime(2017-04-06T08:26:24.041004Z Etc/UTC)>
iex(2)> precision
6
iex(3)> dt2 = %{dt | microsecond: {us, 3}}
#<DateTime(2017-04-06T08:26:24.041Z Etc/UTC)>
iex(4)> dt2 |> Timex.format!("{ISO:Extended}")
"2017-04-06T08:26:24.041+00:00"
```

Comment: This is a great idea, but you should zero-pad the microsecond value `us`.  I ran into an issue where the formatted timestamp's millisecond portion was shifted left one digit.

For example, if `dt` is `#DateTime<2015-11-02 03:08:57.071819Z>`, `dt.microsecond` is `{71819, 6}`.  

Doing `%{dt | microsecond: {71819, 3}} |> Timex.format("{ISO:Extended:Z}")` gives `"2015-11-02T03:08:57.718Z"`.  Notice that the millisecond part is now 718 instead of 071.

To fix this, zero pad the value:  `%{dt | microsecond: {"071819", 3}} |> Timex.format!("{ISO:Extended:Z}")`
"2015-11-02T03:08:57.071Z"

Comment: @GordonZheng I think the right solution here is to divide `us` by `10^<the number of digits that were reduced>`, e.g. 6 -> 3 would be `%{dt | microsecond: {div(us, 1000), 3}} |> Timex.format("{ISO:Extended:Z}")`. Since this works, I'm guessing the behavior of my answer and your comment is a bug -- the value of `us` should be no more than `10^precision`.

Comment: Ah, that's a much better solution.  Thanks @Dogbert!

Answer (score 9):

Since Elixir 1.6.0 there is now the `truncate/2` function present on modules `Time`, `DateTime` and `NativeDateTime` for this.

Here is an example using [`DateTime.truncate/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#truncate/2)

```
iex(1)> dt = Timex.now()
#DateTime<2018-02-16 19:03:51.430946Z>

iex(2)> dt2 = DateTime.truncate(dt, :millisecond)
#DateTime<2018-02-16 19:03:51.430Z>
```